# GWT hosted mode and tomcat deploy differences

Tags: gwt, web

I have a very specific problem dealing with GWT. I have a web application and a jar file which contains the business logic. Inside this jar I use `dozer mapper` and I have the related config file inside the jar itself. The config file is under `META-INF/dozer_mappings.xml`.  While in hosted mode it works perfectly, in web mode it has a problem. It says:

```
Unable to locate dozer mapping file [/META-INF/dozer_mappings.xml] in the classpath!
```

Actually I don't understand why it should change: if the file is not in the classpath it should not work in both the environments... Of course all my libraries are in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The one with the `dozer` configuration is there as well.

Comment: I think you should have put it into WEB-INF directory instead of META-INF... META-INF is just for meta informations, not the configuration itself. Just like you keep web.xml or Spring context.xml in WEB-INF - the same should be with dozer_mappings.xml.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried to add the dozer_mappings.xml file in the WEB-INF itself but it doesn't work. As I mentioned it is inside the core.jar and it should work the same way in both hosted and in web mode. Do you agree? I will try again to put everything in the WEB-INF.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Is your JAR file inside a WAR? Therefore, the JAR itself should be in `WEB-INF/lib` and `lib` directory must be on classpath.

Comment: And the other question is: How to you access the dozer_mappings.xml in the code?

Comment: the first statement is absolutely correct. The dozer_mappings is inside the jar, which in its turn is inside the WAR file when deployed (under WEB-INF/libs). In my application I do use spring and inside the spring.config I have a bean related to dozer. Inside this bean I reference my dozer_mappings. Just a side note: both the dozer_mappings and the spring.cfg are in the same folder, in the destination WAR. It is really strange, it should already be in the classpath. Thanks

Comment: Was it a 'typo' of writing `WEB-INF/libs` with `s` at the end? It should be `WEB-INF/lib` without `s`. If you have deployed you app on Tomcat -> then look here how default classloader works: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html It says, lib is under supervision so it must work provided you don't have typo in directory name, do you?

Comment: hi. yes sorry for that, it was definitely a typo. I will look the link you shared and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: The link you sent it is very interesting but I haven't fixed the problem. In my opinion it is not related to the classloader order but to the jar structure. In the jar the config files are under META-INF and because this is inside the lib folder it should be in the classpath. I tried also to move the config files in the root folder of the jar, without any improvement